# Starting a Class without Form

Tags: c#, winforms, startup

We like to start a Application without a Form (i.e Starting a Class and in this one we want to create the Form instances)

What are the different possiblities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as WinFormsEntryPoint.

Replace this line in Program.cs

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

with

```
Application.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what i'am searching for!

Answer (score 4):

In the application `Main()` delete the lines that create main form and instantiate your class instead. This is (IMHO) the simplest way to do what you need!!

Answer (score 4):

Just change the code that Visual Studio generates for you, that's all. Look for the `Main` method (in Program.cs) and change what it does. When you want to show a UI, create the relevant form and run [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) to start a message loop in the UI thread.

There's nothing magical about what VS does for you here - it just gives you some initial code.